# Get value adapter value "id" in a string (R.string.id)

Tags: android, listadapter

Following is my code to get values from database in a ListAdapter.

I don't want to display the `id` field so I am storing it in `R.string.q_id` but when I try to Toast that view I get an empty value.

Same code works if I try to get `question` or `option1`.

I need **id** to delete the entry from the database using whereClause/ whereArgs

```
ListView lv = getListView();

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListQuestionActivity.this, questionList, R.layout.question_list, new String[]{"id","question", "option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"}, new int[]{R.string.q_id, R.id.question, R.id.option1, R.id.option2, R.id.option3, R.id.option4});
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
                    TextView opt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.option1);
                    final String q_id = view.getResources().getString(R.string.q_id);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), q_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    openOptionsDialog(q_id);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
final String q_id = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.q_id);
```

Instead of

```
final String q_id = view.getResources().getString(R.string.q_id);
```